# CKeditor format copy and paste

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to a button which is like MS word brush icon  [image]. It can be copy and paste the selected font format like font size, color, and so on. Is there any kind of plugin for CK editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/copyformatting) might help:

Allows for quick and easy copying of text formatting between the parts of your document. By default, it provides support for copying text, list and table styles.

Note: Copy Formatting only works with inline styles, so it will not copy or apply block-level styles (e.g. headers) to text.

This plugin comes with great accessibility support and is highly customizable. Refer to the Using the Copy Formatting Feature documentation for more information.